# Entity Framework and separating DAL from domain entities

Tags: entity-framework, orm, separation-of-concerns

If I have a normalized db, it's unlikely to map 1 to 1 with my domain entities. So I customize my EF entities to fit the domain. But now my EF entities are essentially my domain entities and my DAL is baked into my business objects.

On the other hand, if I let my EF entities map 1 to 1 with the db tables, I don't get any advantages of ORM as I just end up manually mapping my domain objects to my EF objects.

How do you get both ORM and separation of concerns?